# A specific quadratic program with non-negativity constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I want to solve the following quadratic program in $x \in \mathbb R^{n}$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \frac 12 x^\top Q \, x + c^\top x\\ \text{subject to} & x \geq 0_n\end{array}$$

where $Q = q I_n$ and $q>0$. I know we can solve a general QP using Lagrangian multipliers and similar methods. However, I was wondering if $Q$ being a multiple of the identity matrix does simplify the problem. Is there a closed-form solution?

Comment: What do you know about vector $c$? And $q$? Note that the QP is non-convex if $q < 0$.

Comment: You might find [this](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~saul/papers/svm_nips02.pdf) paper on non negative quadratic programming useful (looks at a general positive definite $Q$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe write the formula as this form?\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}x^\top Q x+c^\top x= & \frac{q}{2}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_i^2+\frac{c_i}{q}x_i\right)\right)\\
{}= &  \frac{q}{2}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_i+\frac{c_i}{2q}\right)^2-\frac{c_i^2}{4q^2}\right)
\end{align}
So it depends on  $c=(c_1,\dots,c_n)$.
Assume $q>0$, if ${c_i}<0$, then $x_i=-\frac{c_i}{q}$; if $c_i>0$, then $x_i=0$.

Comment: can you please help me with the following problem? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2550644/how-to-formulate-the-dual-problem-in-this-case I like what you did here, and it seems that you know a lot about these. If you could take a look and help out, I would be forever in your debt! Thank you.

Comment: Should it be x_i = \frac{-c_i}{2q} when c_i <0?