# How to formulate the (Lagrangian) dual problem in this case?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems, quadratic-programming

Consider the quadratic programming problem $$\min \frac{1}{2}\langle x, Qx \rangle + \langle c, x \rangle \\ \text{s.t.}\, Ax \geq b $$

where $Q$ is a positive definite matrix of dimension $n$, $A$ is a matrix of dimension $m \times n$, $c \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$.

I need to derive the dual problem.

To that effect, I have formulated the Lagrangian:

$$L(x,\lambda) = \frac{1}{2}\langle x, Qx \rangle + \langle c, x \rangle + \langle \lambda, b-Ax\rangle $$

And after applying the rules of inner products, I get that $$ = \frac{1}{2}\langle x, Qx \rangle + \langle c, x \rangle + \langle \lambda, b \rangle - \langle \lambda, Ax \rangle \\ = \frac{1}{2}\langle x , Qx \rangle + \langle c, x \rangle - \langle A^{T}\lambda, x \rangle + \langle \lambda, b \rangle \\ = \langle \frac{1}{2}Q^{T}x,x \rangle + \langle c - A^{T}\lambda, x \rangle + \langle b, \lambda \rangle \\ = \frac{1}{2}Q^{T}x + c - A^{T}\lambda, x \rangle + \langle b, \lambda \rangle  $$

So, the dual function should have the form $L_{D}(\lambda) = \langle b, \lambda \rangle + \inf \langle \frac{1}{2}Q^{T}x + c - A^{T}\lambda, x \rangle$

**Usually, however, the $\inf$ is taken over the set of all $x$ in some set, and I'm not sure what that set should be in this case. All the problems I have seen thus far have a nonnegativity condition that $x \geq 0$, so this not only helps in figuring out what to take the infimum over, but also in formulating the dual problem.**

**Since I do not have the $x \geq 0$ condition in my problem, I am not sure what to do. Could somebody please help me finish it?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: I have assumed that $Q$ is symmetric below. Since
$\langle x, Q x \rangle = \langle x, {1 \over 2} (Q + Q^T) x \rangle$,
there is no loss of generality in doing so (just replace $Q$ by
${1 \over 2} (Q + Q^T)$ in the resulting formulae).

Informally, we have the primal 
$\inf_x \sup_{\lambda \ge 0} L(x,\lambda)$ and we swap the $\inf, \sup$ to get the dual
$\sup_{\lambda \ge 0} \inf_x L(x, \lambda)$.

Since $Q>0$ we can solve $\inf_x L(x, \lambda)$ by solving for the first order conditions
$Qx+c-A^T \lambda = 0$ to get $x = Q^{-1} (A^T \lambda -c)$.

Then the dual is $\sup_{\lambda \ge 0} L(Q^{-1} (A^T \lambda -c), \lambda)$.

Comment: isn't it $Q^{T}x+c-A^{T}\lambda = 0$, though?

Comment: Usually $Q$ is symmetric in these sorts of problems, otherwise replace $Q$ by ${1 \over 2} (Q+Q^T)$. The cost function remains the same.

Comment: In fact, if we keep the $\frac{1}{2}$ in so that we let the first order conditions be $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}Q^{T}x+c-A^{T}\lambda = 0$, then $x = (Q^{-1})^{T}(2A^{T}\lambda -2c)$. Why isn't it? Also, how then do you get the dual **problem**?

Comment: No, the derivative of the cost function is ${1 \over 2}(Q+Q^T) x + c-A^T \lambda$.

Comment: But assuming that $Q$ is symmetric in the first place is simpler, and usual for these sorts of things.

Comment: what about the dual problem though? What happens to the constraints?

Comment: The constraints appear in $L$, and are $\lambda \ge 0$.

Comment: I guess what I mean to say is whether there are any conditions under which the inf might not be finite? For example, in the LPP $\text{minimize}\, \langle c, x \rangle$, subject to $Ax \geq b$, $x \geq 0$, the Lagrangian is $L(x ,\lambda) = \langle c, x \rangle + \langle \lambda, b-Ax \rangle = \langle c - A^{T}\lambda, x \rangle + \langle b, \lambda \rangle$. Then the dual function has the form $L_{D}(\lambda) = \langle b, \lambda \rangle + \inf _{x \geq 0} \langle c - A^{T}\lambda, x \rangle$. Then, since the $\inf$ is finite iff $c-A^{T}\lambda \geq 0$, we must have that...

Comment: $L_{D}(\lambda) = \begin{cases} \langle b, \lambda \rangle & \text{if} \, A^{T}\lambda \leq c, \\ -\infty & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$ 

I originally had this problem in my question, but removed it because I thought it was too long and nobody would bother reading it. But really, what I wanted to know was how to write the solution in this form.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. The dual cost function is always finite when $Q>0$, but  if the feasible set is empty then the primal has value $+\infty$ by convention. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: would that convention then make the dual have value $-\infty$?

Comment: No, in this case the dual is finite.

Comment: honestly, I'm not sure then, because the problem I used as an example here is linear, not quadratic. In the quadratic case, the process might be different.

Comment: but one thing that would be really helpful would be if you would show me how to solve for $x$ in the case where $Q$ is not symmetric, because that is not explicitly stated in the problem I am working on.

Comment: I am not following you. The problem above is quadratic. The dual is the $\max$ of a quadratic with Hessian $-Q <0$, hence has bounded $\max$. If the primal is infeasible then the primal has no solution.

Comment: As I wrote above, replace $Q$ by ${1 \over 2}(Q+Q^T)$.

Comment: I know replace $Q$ by $\frac{1}{2}(Q + Q^{T})$. What I am asking is, to solve $\frac{1}{2}(Q+Q^{T})x + c - A^{T}\lambda = 0$ for $x$, am I going to get $x = [2Q^{-1}+2(Q^{T})^{-1}](A^{T}\lambda - c)$?

Comment: Of course not. You will get $x= ({1 \over 2}(Q+Q^T))^{-1} (A^T \lambda -c)$.

Comment: Solve ${\partial L(x,\lambda) \over \partial x} = 0$. You will see how the $Q+Q^T$ arises.

Comment: one last thing, and then I'll go away: If I wanted to write the dual problem in the form "Maximize ___________" subject to "_____", how would I express what we have above in that form?

Comment: $\max \{ L(Q^{-1} (A^T \lambda -c), \lambda) | \lambda \ge 0 \}$. However, you should do the algebra and simplify the cost, I am too lazy/busy to do it.

Comment: but that's only when $Q$ is symmetric.

Comment: Replace $Q$ by ${1 \over 2} (Q+Q^T)$. You need to try and understand where this is coming from. The cost is the same whether you use $Q$ or the symmetrised version, but the derivative is sensitive to whether or not it is symmetric. You can assume that $Q$ is symmetric in the first place if you want, or just replace $Q$ by the symmetrised version.